# Hosting a spring boot app with maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, hosting, openshift

i have a web project with spring boot, and managed by maven.
Now i want to host it (first in a free hosting for test it) and run it with

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

, but i don't know if i have to change all downloading the dependencies and setting them local to my repo, cause maven would try to download it in a permission denied folder.

I have the project hosted in Openshift, but i can change it if neccesarry.

When i try to run it in my app-root/repo folder, the error thrown is like this:

> [ERROR] Could not create local repository at /var/lib/openshift/55889cd7..../.m2/repository

Here is my pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>...
.....
...</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <start-class>control.Application</start-class>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And the basic application class:

```
package control    

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

I would be very grateful if someone could help me.

Comment: No you don't want to run it with maven. You want to build a jar, upload that and do `java -jar your-jar.jar`...

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: control/Application : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Comment: Make sure that you are compiling with a supported java version, probably you are using java8 and that isn't supported on your host.

Comment: Finally it works, i had to change a port with "java -jar *.jar --server.port=${OPENSHIFT_DIY_PORT} --server.address=${OPENSHIFT_DIY_IP}"